# Azure Media Services AssetDeliveryPolicies in REST Api - do they gone?

Tags: rest, azure, azure-media-services

I'm writing application in which i upload video, encode it, and then i need to expose a link to encoded video. One of the steps is to create `AssetDeliveryPolicies` and link it to Asset, i tried to do that, but to my surprise i don't see such entity as `AssetDeliveryPolicies` on that endpoint:

```
 https://wamsamsclus001rest-hs.cloudapp.net/api/AssetDeliveryPolicies
```

Do anybody have tried to do something like that? I'm not sure whether i'm doing something wrong or it is already deprecated and handled in some other way.

Answer (score 1):

### Create an AccessDeliveryPolicy

```
POST https://media.windows.net/api/AssetDeliveryPolicies HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;NetFx
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx
Accept: application/json
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
Authorization: Bearer [token here]
x-ms-version: 2.11
x-ms-client-request-id: [guid here]
Host: media.windows.net

{"Name":"Clear Policy",
"AssetDeliveryProtocol":7,
"AssetDeliveryPolicyType":2,
"AssetDeliveryConfiguration":null}
```

Link an AssetDeliveryPolicy to an Asset.

```
POST https://media.windows.net/api/Assets('nb%3Acid%3AUUID%3A86933344-9539-4d0c-be7d-f842458693e0')/$links/DeliveryPolicies HTTP/1.1
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;NetFx
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx
Accept: application/json
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer [token here]
x-ms-version: 2.11
x-ms-client-request-id: [new guid here]
Host: media.windows.net

{"uri":"https://media.windows.net/api/AssetDeliveryPolicies('nb%3Aadpid%3AUUID%3A92b0f6ba-3c9f-49b6-a5fa-2a8703b04ecd')"}
```

Where `nb%3Acid%3AUUID%3A86933344-9539-4d0c-be7d-f842458693e0` is the URL Encoded value of AssetId and `nb%3Aadpid%3AUUID%3A92b0f6ba-3c9f-49b6-a5fa-2a8703b04ecd` is the URL Encoded value of the AccessDeliveryPolicy Id.

[Source](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-rest-configure-asset-delivery-policy/)